# Dependency injection RoleStore with ninject

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ninject, owin, identity

Hey I am trying to bind the IRoleStore to the Rolestore but I keep getting an error. I use the same code for the application user and that goes well, but as example I'll show that one here aswell :

```
kernel.Bind<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole>>().To<RoleStore<ApplicationRole>>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("context", 
        context => kernel.Get<InBuildingNavigatorDbContext>());
kernel.Bind<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();

kernel.Bind<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().To<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("context", 
        context => kernel.Get<InBuildingNavigatorDbContext>());
kernel.Bind<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

And I get the error:

> The type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.RoleStore<InBuildingNavigator.Data.Models.ApplicationRole>' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 'IBindingToSyntax<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole>>.To<TImplementation>()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.RoleStore<InBuildingNavigator.Data.Models.ApplicationRole>' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IRoleStore<InBuildingNavigator.Data.Models.ApplicationRole>'.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blind shot, but you may try :

```
kernel.Bind<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, string>>().To<RoleStore<ApplicationRole>>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("context", 
        context => kernel.Get<InBuildingNavigatorDbContext>());
```

According to [`RoleStore` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468181(v=vs.108).aspx) RoleStore implements `IRoleStore<TRole, string>`, not `IRoleStore<TRole>`

Comment: I tried this and it indeed fixed the error, but I redid the whole role thing so it isn't as relevant anymore. but thanks anyway, it did indeed fix it! :)